# How do we programmatically check if the android phone supports external SD cards?

Tags: android, android-sdcard, android-memory

How to programmatically check if an Android phone offers **support for external SD card** or not?

Please note that I do not wish to check if external SD card is added to the phone or not, I wish to find out if the phone offers *support* for the same.

**EDIT:** I want to make my question more clear. I want to know if the **phone hardware** supports external SD card or not.

Answer (score -2):

I found an indirect way of doing this:

As soon as you try to access the storage path

```
"/storage/external_SD"
```

if hardware support is not there for external SD card, you get an exception. So I found a way to solve my problem.

Comment: Who said that that is the storage path? It could have been /storage/sdcard2 or /storage/extSdCard or many other paths. I think what you want is impossible.

Comment: True, but in my case, I am working only on a specific brand of phones, wherein this path is uniform throughout. So it seems to be a decent solution, under the constrained conditions.